# CSV attachment, replacing \n from cell values

Tags: apex, attachment, blob, escape

I am trying to create a csv attachment through apex, I am getting the csv with the values. But some values for eg. '**Hi I am xyz.
\n This is an example code.**
'
 are getting split to next cell because of the escape sequence '\n' in the value itself. Is there any way to skip the break and next line html escape tags??

```
    if(attList != null && attList.size()>0){
    for(Attribute__c att : attList)
    {
        if(rows != null){
            rows = rows + att.Name +',';
            rows = rows+ att.Value__c+',';      
        }
        rows = rows + '\n';
    }
}
if(rows == null){
    rows = '';
}

if(csvFileData != null){
    csvFileData += rows;
}else{
    csvFileData = headerName + '\n' + rows;
}
csvFileData = csvFileData.replace('null','');
DateTime currenttime = DateTime.now();
String strConvertedDate = currenttime.format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'Australia/Sydney');
String fileName = 'Attribute list' + ' ' +strConvertedDate+'.csv';
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
attach.Body = Blob.valueof(csvFileData);
attach.Name = fileName;
attach.ParentID = pc.Id;
attachmentList.add(attach);
system.debug('attachmentList-->'+attachmentList.size());

if(!attachmentList.isEmpty()){
    database.insert(attachmentList, true);
}
```